# Refresh JLabel Percent Java

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, percentage, event-dispatch-thread

I have a downloader which shows me percents, but then I added a JLabel and it doesn't refresh. So it keeps at 0%. Now my question is, how do I update the JLabel every second?

```
loaderText = "Loading is at "+TextDownloader.percentage+"%..";
JLabel loaderLabel = new JLabel(loaderText, JLabel.CENTER);
loaderLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
aJPanel.add(loaderLabel);
```

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead implement a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: Also consider using a [`JProgressBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html) instead of the `JLabel` or a [`ProgressMonitorInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitorInputStream.html) instead of either.

Comment: The code shown seems to continuously add a label too, but I assume that is just from code extraction for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `java.swing.Timer` class to refresh the graphics component every second:

```
final JLabel loaderLabel = new JLabel(JLabel.CENTER);
loaderLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
aJPanel.add(loaderLabel);

java.swing.Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
    String loaderText = "Loading is at "+TextDownloader.percentage+"%..";
    loaderLabel.setText(loaderText);
};);
timer.start();
```

Comment: `TextDownloader` is most likely blocking the EDT so none of that code will make a visual change before it ends.

Comment: "Most likely"? Can you please give me a link to the sources? I've never seen that code.

Comment: *"link to the sources"*  Repeated from above comment to Bert.  *See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.*

Comment: I know about concurrency in Swing. I said about `TextDownloader` sources. My code does not perform any hard business logic, so it should work as well.

Comment: Just saying based on an educated guess.  Mind you, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) from the OP would be the way to settle the matter.